# Get Field Data Types (SPFieldType?) as JSON

Tags: 2010, rest, json

I'm building some python programs that transfer data from SharePoint 2010 to and from a database.

Previously, I've been receiving REST queries as XML and parsing through it in order to first get the fields names and data types (like `int`, `string`, `DateTime`, etc...), then the actual data.

Most of the time this works fine, but it's much easier, more flexible, and much more consistent to get what I need out of it when I return it as a JSON and translate that to a python dictionary.

The only issue is that all of the values are returned as `string` objects. So, I was wondering if there was a way to get a `FieldName: SPFieldType` mapping from the REST, as a JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the web (not the list) with a $metadata call.

```
https://not.really.mine/siteCol/Site/Web/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata
```

Then either cache the resulting XML and process it once for the list

-OR-

Use an XSLT transform to parse your metadata return into JSON and see if the result is close enough and quick enough.
[XSL 1.0 XML to JSON transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122921/xsl-to-convert-xml-to-json) (Code below)

The result isn't super convenient to parse, but it should come out like this:

```
           <exerpt>
           <EntityType Name="TestCasesItem">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="ContentTypeID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" m:FC_TargetPath="SyndicationTitle" m:FC_ContentKind="text" m:FC_KeepInContent="true" />
            <Property Name="TestingStepProcess" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="ExpectedOutcome" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="ActualOutcome" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Pass" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="CommentsIssues" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="TestDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="AssignmentDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Regression" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Script" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="TestGroup" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="TestSuite" Relationship="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TestCasesItem_TestSuite" FromRole="TestCasesItem" ToRole="TestSuite" />
            <Property Name="TestSuiteValue" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="CreatedBy" Relationship="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TestCasesItem_CreatedBy" FromRole="TestCasesItem" ToRole="CreatedBy" />
            <Property Name="CreatedById" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="ModifiedBy" Relationship="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TestCasesItem_ModifiedBy" FromRole="TestCasesItem" ToRole="ModifiedBy" />
            <Property Name="ModifiedById" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Modified" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true" m:FC_TargetPath="SyndicationUpdated" m:FC_ContentKind="text" m:FC_KeepInContent="true" />
            <Property Name="Created" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="DontTryIt" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ContentType" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="Owshiddenversion" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true" ConcurrencyMode="Fixed" />
            <Property Name="Version" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Attachments" Relationship="Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TestCasesItem_Attachments" FromRole="TestCasesItem" ToRole="Attachments" />
            <Property Name="Path" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
        </EntityType>
       </exerpt Type="Malformed XML, but you get the idea">
```

Interesting XSL transform code (Credited in header)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" :<xsl:call-template name="Properties">
        <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="'Yes'"> </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:param name="parent"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$parent='Yes'"> <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>":"<xsl:value-of  select="."/>"</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>           
        </xsl:when>                
        <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of  select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>{
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```